# Get Wordpress Category ID from a URL string

Tags: php

How can you get the category ID of "category-name" from a nice URL (e.g. http://www.example.com/category/category-name/)?

I need to retrieve the category ID from a URL of wordpress because this function will be used in wp_nav_menu() since the design of the site is to have a dropdown of latest post under the category, so if it is not a category of wordpress (link to home page or about page), then there should be on dropdown.

I found this site(http://ditlo.com/) to be an example of the problem :)

Comment: You mean, from the URL? Or from within the page?

Comment: From within a page, but need to get the category ID based from a URL. To why, I'm placing the category links to Wordpress's built in Navigation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$cat = get_category_by_path('http://www.example.com/category/category-name/')
```

Reference http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_by_path

Answer (score 0):

You will want a couple of steps:

1. [`get_category_by_slug( $slug )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_by_slug) - Call this with the URL fragment (the slug) as an arg, and it'll give you a category object.
2. `$category->cat_ID` - Call this on the `$category` object to return the ID of the category.

A one-liner would look like: `$slug_ID = get_category_by_slug($slug)->cat_ID;`